# Change Chrome language through JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, internationalization

I have implemented internationalization using `i18n`. I know i can't change language at runtime using `chrome.i18n`. Is there any way I can change Chrome language programmatically using JS? Any lib or custom code.

Comment: I certainly hope you're not able to. Otherwise any extension might decide to change my browser's language to something I don't speak and changing back would be very hard or impossible. Especially if the extension changes is back.

Comment: You can write a separate utility that changes the user profile preferences file and restarts the browser. Such utility can be written in any language and is to be installed separately so then your extension can launch it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). Practically though, extensions that want to provide independent language setting have to use an independent localization library, there are lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not. Browser's language cannot be changed by an extension.

If you need to do this for testing purposes, I would suggest you to just start another instance of the browser passing the correct language from command line, for example:

```
LANGUAGE=it google-chrome
```